# Pull information from a web page (after JS has fired), Joomla, PHP, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am supposed to create a web service which is capable of pulling dynamic information from a website that has Joomla running the service.

Problem is that whenever I try to DOM -request the site, I get either a null DOM object or a stripped down website, without the information I needed.

The thing is that the website loads before the JS (that has all the information in it) loads. I am trying to pull the information using php, yet no avail.

I'm not that experienced with DOM or pulling information from different CMS's.

Comment: Instead of listing multiple things like `php` in title, add the most appropriate 5 in tags...

Comment: Being new on this site, I have my flaws. I've corrected the tags.

Comment: _"DOM -request the site"_ what does this mean?

Comment: Could you confirm that the data that you are after, is loaded through Javascript / jQuery on the website.